# recover from an Exception, scala Future

Tags: scala

Why does this scala code compile,
The signature of recover is,

```
def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U]
```

then why does below code compile.  You can see that `recover` in below code doesn't return a Unit.

```
 object TestRecover {

    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.Future

    def failingFunction(input: Seq[String]): Future[Unit] = {
      Future {
        if (input.isEmpty) throw new Exception("Cannot be empty")
        else ()
      }
    }

    def callFailingFunc(input: Seq[String]): Future[Unit] = {
      failingFunction(input).recover {
        case _ =>
          //Not returning Unit here, but Future[Unit]. Shouldn't type checker fail this ?
          callFailingFunc(input.reverse)
      }
    }
  }
```

Also why `Await.result(TestRecover.callFailingFunc(Seq()), 20.seconds)` doesn't produce stackoverflow because of infinite recursion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then why does below code compile. You can see that recover in below code doesn't return a Unit.

The compiler is 'helping' you a bit and does an implicit conversion from `Future[Unit]` to `Unit`. Effectively compiling it like this.

```
def callFailingFunc(input: Seq[String]): Future[Unit] = {
  failingFunction(input).recover {
    case _ =>
      //Not returning Unit here, but Future[Unit]. Shouldn't type checker fail this ?
      callFailingFunc(input.reverse)
      ()
  }
}
```

This blog explains is very nicely: http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/10/implicit-conversion-to-unit-type-in.html

> Also why Await.result(TestRecover.callFailingFunc(Seq()), 20.seconds) doesn't produce stackoverflow because of infinite recursion ?

You don't get a stack overflow because every call to `failingFunction` will create a new `Future` with a new stack.